# Лицензия скрипта php

Tags: php, лицензирование

Всем привет.

Ребята, подскажите, какие на данный момент есть эффективные способы держать лицензию скрипта?

Из всех комментов так и не увидел норм предложения. :(

Comment: Что именно понимается под лицензией? Бумажка о зарегистрированном программном продукте? Невозможность просмотра кода другими программистами? Запрет изменения и контроль использования кода?

Comment: Самое главное избавится от NULL версий. Сам скрипт стоит копейки, но когда есть NULL, то неохота что-то делать. Такой скрипт на заказ пишут от 30К, и то будете мозг парить себе и исполнителю, это я говорю, так как я написал его. А тут готовое все за 1К. Вот и хочу сделать лицензию, хоть и для узкого круга лиц.

Comment: Сделай скрипт сервисом, размести на своем сервере и раздай доступ ограниченному кругу лиц.

Comment: Это юкоз уже, вот это и не нравится никому. Был опыт, но нехорошие люди пробили файлы лицензии через nginx/access.log, а там дело техники. :(

Comment: На ucoz размещать закрытые проекты - глупость. Оставлять доступ посторонним к access.log - еще большая глупость. Я с трудом понимаю ваш язык, старайтесь писать более ясно и подучите русский.

Comment: "Сделай скрипт сервисом, размести на своем сервере" - Это "юкоз", я пример привел. :)) Не хочу так, вот и спрашиваю. access.log  доступен был каждому, кто владел лицензией, скрипт под ioncube распространялся. Вот после первых нулов ищу альтернативу.

Comment: В коде делаем проверку каких-то переменных, размещенных на своем сервере. Для каждого покупателя лицензии - уникальные значения проверочных переменных. При этом каждому обладателю лицензии устанавливаем ограничения, например, на ip или имена сайтов, с которых производится проверка. Все это можно автоматизировать при первом запуске скрипта. Если появились те, кто не покупал лицензию, то запрещаем у них работу скрипта, т.е. удаляем их переменные со своего сервера. Для того, чтобы никто не догадался - делаем обфускацию кода.

Comment: Обфускация в планах, остальное проблема пройдена на практике и за недоступности моего сервера. Нет ни одного мега ДЦ, чтоб онлайн 100%. Скрыть запрос хоть к лицензии, хоть от лицензии невозможно. И в этом и есть моя проблема. Вот как можно в этом плане защитить?

Comment: @wwwplaton, в чем проблема взять два сервера в разных ДЦ и настроить round-robin DNS? Они стоят сейчас копейки. Я молчу уж о том, что на DO у меня аптайм стопроцентный.